# What is this part in 556 die

Tags: integrated-circuit

I ask this question, just out of curiosity. In this die of 556 IC, what are the wave-like squiggle at the four corners, and two more on the top?

[image]

Comment: Awesome! We need more semiconductor design questions here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those are high-current NPN transistors. Here, from the [designer's book](http://www.designinganalogchips.com/):

[image]

Comment: Great! I never would have guessed that.

Comment: Book downloads are broken, so here's a direct link: http://www.designinganalogchips.com/_count/designinganalogchips.pdf

Comment: Thanks, George, the book is excellent (and free) unless you insist on the print version.

Answer (score 5):

Those are the large transistors required to drive the output pins: two for each of the totem-pole main outputs and one for each of the open-collector discharge pins. Those transistors need to handle on the order of 200 mA each, so they need to be much larger than the internal analog/logic transistors.